# jQuery custom content tooltip shows nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Following the tooltip tutorials from [jQuery UI API](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) I'm trying to create tooltips with custom html content, but nothing shows up. Console shows no errors with my script, only some from the jQuery-UI (but nothing special).

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
      items: "custom-tooltip",
      content: function() {
        var element = $(this);
        if (element.is("custom-tooltip")) {
          return "<a>THIS<br/>IS<br/><A><br/>TOOLTIP!";
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CUSTOM TOOLTIPS</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="tooltips.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h3><a href="#" custom-tooltip="">HOVER ME</a></h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.is` function requires a selector. To match an attribute if it exists, surround it in square brackets `[]`:

```
    if (element.is("[custom-tooltip]")) {
```

Same with the `items` option:

```
     items: "[custom-tooltip]",
```

The rest of your code looks fine. Note that you probably don't need the `if` check at all since `items` will already restrict the widget to the same tags.

More info on valid selectors can be found in the documentation pages: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Well this is just a case where I want it to work with something simple, the If is there for when I want multiple tooltips on multiple elements I guess, or is there a simpler way? Like if I have 5 different tooltips for 5 different elements, I'll make and if sentence for every element

Comment: The conventional way would be to use a `title`. But if you're loading content dynamically, what you have is a good simple way of doing it. [One of the examples on the jqueryui page](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content) does the same

Answer (score 1):

See this  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9cfor3/1/). You make some mistake in you tool-tip settings.
Tooltip items setting should be like this :  `items: "[custom-tooltip]"`
and why you are calling documenting ready function this way

```
$(document).ready(function() { -- document ready event
  $(function() { -- same document ready
    $(document).tooltip(...);
  });
});
```

jQuery code would be like:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
      items: "[custom-tooltip]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $(this);
        if (element.is("[custom-tooltip]")) {
          return "<a>THIS<br/>IS<br/><A><br/>TOOLTIP!";
        }
      }
    });
 });
```